# Как обойти односвязный список и вернуть все численные значения в один массив

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Вот мой код, в комментариях описал что происходит.
Суть в том, что возвращает не один массив [1, 2, 3, 4] А 5 разных с одним числом.

```
'use strict';

function reversePrint(linkedList) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let key in linkedList) { // Перебираем свойства
    if (typeof linkedList[key] === 'number') { // если свойство число, то сохраняем его в массив
      arr.push(linkedList[key]);
    } else if ((typeof linkedList[key] === 'object') && (typeof linkedList[key] !== null)) { // Если свойство объект и не null, рекурсивно обходим его
      reversePrint(linkedList[key]);
    } 

  }

 return alert(arr); // Возвращаем массив.. Но нет, возвращается 5 массивом с числом и один из них пустой. Помогите пожалуйста найти где я ошибся.

}

const someList = {
  value: 1,
  next: {
    value: 2,
    next: {
      value: 3,
      next: {
        value: 4,
        next: null
      }
    }
  }
};
reversePrint(someList);
```

Comment: `alert` ничего не возвращает. поэтому `return alert(...)` равносильно `return;` Плюс, при **каждом** вызове функции создается **свой**  массив `let arr = [];`

Comment: В данном случае если использовать return arr; Возвращается массив с числом 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустил детскую ошибку, забыл что при рекурсии переобьявляю новый массив. Спасибо Grundy

Я ошибся, это не многоуровневый объект, а односвязный список. Поправил сабж